# getElementsByTagName Jquery

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'cant seem to access the following XML child / nodes:

```
<quotation>
<length category="3month">
  <newprice>test1</newprice>
  <save><?php echo number_format((($ThreeMonthPrice*12)+35),2)?></save>
  <payments><?php echo number_format($ThreeMonthPrice,2)?></payments>
  <price><?php echo number_format($ThreeMonthPrice,2)?></price>
</length>
<length category="6month">
  <newprice>test1</newprice>
  <save><?php echo number_format((($SixMonthPrice*12)+35),2)?></save>
  <payments><?php echo number_format($SixMonthPrice,2)?></payments>
  <price><?php echo number_format($SixMonthPrice,2)?></price>
</length>
</quotation>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
ThreeMonthPrice=data.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
SixMonthPrice=data.getElementsByTagName("price")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong??

I getting the following error in the console:

Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Thanks,

---

Managed to fix this, I had to many getElementsByTagName.

All is working OK now.

Comment: where/how is data defined

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FG9Nz/

It seems to be bringing back all the elements?

Comment: Kevin B - it's in an XML file...

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/FG9Nz/1/ , I dont get the error..

Comment: Don't see why this is tagged with jQuery but ok. And if you had "too many `getElementsByTagName`" (whatever that is) then maybe the question is too localized.

Comment: This is not jQuery code. There is not even a whiff of jQuery. This seems to avoid jQuery at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you used XML file content as html and in the result box in jsfiddle show your xml content not your result of your javascript code and in console you can see error **data is not defined**:

I try to fixed it, at the first i don`t edit html box in jsfiddle that have your xml file content and jsfiddle write all of codes in body tag in result box then if i get content of body i get all xml contents as string, then i convert string content to xml content with a little javascript function then i use your query to find price tag and then write it in body.

```
function StringtoXML(text){
                if (window.ActiveXObject){
                  var doc=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                  doc.async='false';
                  doc.loadXML(text);
                } else {
                  var parser=new DOMParser();
                  var doc=parser.parseFromString(text,'text/xml');
                }
                return doc;
            }

    //example of application:
    var doc = StringtoXML($(document.body).html());

ThreeMonthPrice=doc.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

$(document.body).html("&pound;"+ThreeMonthPrice);
```

check it here http://jsfiddle.net/FG9Nz/2/